# How to auto-fit a left-to-right list?

Tags: tasks

For instance,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task D
\task E
\task F
\end{tasks}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tasks}(5)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task D
\task E
\task F
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

I want to list my list so that it makes automatically the width of the page full, and it does not matter the way that can be achieved.

[image]

These are some of them, taken by my phone:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your objective isn't entirely clear. Please edit your posting to explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve. And, do indicate whether a solution has to make use of the `tasks` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a task which spans the while line, you can use the starred version `\task*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{tasks}(3)
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task A
\task B
\task C
\task! spans the whole line
\task*(2) spans 2 columns
\task C
\task* spans more than one column
\end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Actually, I see this style in a math book. There are expressions that are different in length but they are  arranged so that it fills (fits) the width regardless of the length of the expression.

Comment: So, is this the right one ?

Comment: @Ali, so I think 2nd option is what you want. Try to insert longer items.

Comment: @Ali Can you maybe add an image of what you see in the math book? I'm still not really sure what layout you are looking for.

Comment: I have added some of them.

Comment: @Ali Please have a look at my edited answer. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @samcarter But some cases are two and there are cases where there are 4 and 3

Comment: @Ali How many columns you have is up to you by setting `(3)`

Comment: @samcarter it is tedious to do it manually.

Comment: @samcarter By the way, I do not know if this book is written via LATEX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82161/discussion-between-ali-and-samcarter).

Comment: @samcarter how to make in {\settasks} the \task in bold ?

Comment: @Ali Comments are really not a good place to ask new questions. Open a new question and much more people will see it

Comment: @Ali or have a look at the documentation, chapter 4 http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tasks/tasks_en.pdf